# How to do Setup of mocks with Ninject's MockingKernel (moq)

Tags: ninject, moq, ninject-mockingkernel

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure how I can do `.SetupXXX()` calls on the underlying `Mock<T>` that has been generated inside the `MockingKernel`. Anyone who can shed some light on how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to call the `GetMock<T>` method on the `MoqMockingKernel` which will return the generated `Mock<T>` on which you can call your `.SetupXXX()/VerifyXXX()` methods.

Here is an example unit test which demonstrates the `GetMock<T>` usage:

```cs
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var mockingKernel = new MoqMockingKernel();
    var serviceMock = mockingKernel.GetMock<IService>();
    serviceMock.Setup(m => m.GetGreetings()).Returns("World");
    var sut = mockingKernel.Get<MyClass>();
    Assert.AreEqual("Hello World", sut.SayHello());    
}
```

Where the involved types are the following:

```cs
public interface IService { string GetGreetings(); }

public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IService service;

    public MyClass(IService service) { this.service = service; }

    public string SayHello()
    {
        return string.Format("Hello {0}", service.GetGreetings());
    }
}
```

Note that you can access the generated `Moq.MockRepository` (if you prefer it over the SetupXXX methods) with the `MoqMockingKernel.MockRepository` property.

Comment: Thanks! I only focused on the MoqModule etc. - not the MoqMockingKernel.